# MemoryStream -> Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: vb.net, memorystream

I'm trying to implement a library ["Boleto2Net"](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boleto2net), I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNqWe-veMno) in YouTube and I downloaded his example... But I'm having problem with this line:

```
    'GERA ARQUIVO DE REMESSA
    Dim st As New MemoryStream
    Dim arquivo As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\remessa.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)


    Dim remessa = New ArquivoRemessa(objBoletos.Banco, TipoArquivo.CNAB400, 500) ' If I coment this line, the error doesn't occurs
    remessa.GerarArquivoRemessa(objBoletos, st) ' If I coment this line, the error doesn't occurs

    st.WriteTo(arquivo)
    arquivo.Close()
    st.Close()
```

I'm getting `Cannot access a closed Stream` error, I really doesn't know how memory streans works and how to deal with it, I tried to find an "Open" or "Close" command for memorystream, but there's none.

Comment: Could you update your post adding a definition for the ArquivoRemessa type and GerarArquivoRemessa method?  My Portuguese is very rusty but guessing this is a custom type FileShipment?  You might also benefit from reading up on _Using_ clause and how it applies to IDisposable implementations (Such as streams)

Comment: You say that you tried to find a `MemoryStream.Close` method and couldn't, yet you're calling it in that code. ALWAYS read the documentation for new types and members. It's a simple click in the code and press F1. As for the issue, it's obviously in that `GerarArquivoRemessa` method, so we definitely need to see that. Mind you, if you look at that then you can probably see for yourself where that stream is being closed.

Comment: The stream must be being closed in that `GerarArquivoRemessa` method. If the exception is telling you that the stream is closed when you call that method and not otherwise then that must be where it's being closed. Do you have access to the code for that method, or is it in a compiled library?